# What is $x^3 + x + 1$ for $x=\frac{\sqrt 5 - 1}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> What is $x^3 + x + 1$ for $x=\frac{\sqrt 5 - 1}{2}$

Of course we can subtitute and expand it

${(\frac{\sqrt 5 -1}{2})}^3 + \frac{\sqrt 5 -1}{2} + 1$

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 6):

Since $x^2=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}=1-x$, $x^3=x-x^2=2x-1$, so $x^3+x+1=3x$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. $\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ is a root of $x^2+x-1=0$. So $x^2=1-x$.

Multiply by $x$ to get

$$x^3=x-x^2=x-1+x=2x-1$$

Therefore

$$x^3+x+1=3x=\frac{3}{2}(\sqrt{5}-1)$$